# String encode memory utilisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, character-encoding, garbage-collection

```
str = 'text ....' //lets say size=100mb
str_utf8_size = len(str.encode('utf8'))
```

In python 3, I would like to know how Python's `str.encode()` works with respect to memory utilization

In the above code is it creating a copy of str and utilizing twice the memory (=200mb?)

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about 200MB unless you're doing a *huge* number of them at the same time. I suspect this may be a cause of premature-optimization, which is well-known as a "bad thing" — see [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Yes I am dealing with huge text size, and performance is of big concern

Comment: I didn't mean a single big text string, I meant **many** of them simultaneously. 200MB by itself is not a big deal with software running on today's hardware.

Comment: yes i mean with both text size and many of them simultaneously

Comment: If you already have many 100 MB strings in memory, is one more 100 MB really a problem?

Comment: In that case, Python supports [Incremental Encoding and Decoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#incremental-encoding-and-decoding) which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> In the above code is it creating a copy of str and utilizing twice the memory (=200mb?)

No, the encoded string can be smaller or larger than the string. Examples:

```
aaa...aa毛
string size:  2000076
encoded size: 1000036

õõõ...õõõ
string size:  1000073
encoded size: 2000033
```

Code to produce that ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SKFYITNPQT1RXUFLwdBAS8tMQVtB/dn62eo6CuqHt8JFrbgUgKCgKDOvRCNNvbo42so4tlZPTw/I0jW2iq1V10RSoF5cAqTTFYozq1KtFIAmFevFx4M4@Wnx8RqaKEpT85LzU1JTIGrBSiEiGuqlJWkW6po4dWr@/w8A)):

```
for s in 'a' * 10**6 + '毛', 'õ' * 10**6:
    print(f'{s[:3]}...{s[-3:]}')
    print('string size: ', s.__sizeof__())
    print('encoded size:', s.encode('utf8').__sizeof__())
    print()
```